# I can't isplaying Child pages of the current page in post format (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I took [this code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) from the Wordpress codex which displays Child pages of the current page in post format.

I created a Page called **"Home"** and assigned a template called **Front Page** to it:

**front-page.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */
 get_header(); ?>
 <div id="intro">
  <div id="tagline">
   <?php // Retrieve a list of latest posts or post(s) matching criteria).
   $args = array('category_name' => 'Tagline', 'numberposts' => 1, 'order' => 'DESC');
   $customposts = get_posts($args);
   foreach($customposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div><!-- #tagline -->
  <div id="featured">
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'intro_image'); ?>" />
  </div>
 </div><!-- #intro -->
 <div id="main-content">
  <div id="main-content-first">
   <?php // Retrieve a list of latest posts or post(s) matching criteria).
   $args = array('category_name' => 'Main Content First');
   $customposts = get_posts($args);
   foreach($customposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="main-content-middle">
   <?php // Retrieve a list of latest posts or post(s) matching criteria).
   $args = array('category_name' => 'Main Content Middle');
   $customposts = get_posts($args);
   foreach($customposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="main-content-last">
   <?php // Retrieve a list of latest posts or post(s) matching criteria).
   $args = array('category_name' => 'Main Content Last');
   $customposts = get_posts($args);
   foreach($customposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
 </div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
 $mypages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');
 $count = 0;
 foreach($mypages as $page)
 {
  $content = $page->post_content;
  if(!$content)
   continue;
  if($count >= 2)
   break;
  $count++;
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
 ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h2>
  <div class="entry"><?php echo $content ?></div>
 <?php
 }
?>


 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then I made the **About** page its child (Home page's child).

For some reason nothing is being displayed (see at the bottom of the template)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your issue is that $post is assigned inside of the loop, and that code is placed outside of the loop.

The problem might just be the one instance of $post->ID; your page's structure is pretty weird. Try using this line instead of the similar one you posted:

`$mypages = get_pages('child_of='.$wp_query->post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');`

Comment: Do you mean I ahve to place it inside this loop?: `get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
     <?php } else { ?> 
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
     <?php } ?>    

      <?php the_content(); ?>
      <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '' ) ); ?>
      <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '', '' ); ?>

    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Yep! Please give that a shot. A lot of WP functions only run inside The Loop.

Comment: @aendrew in which part of the loop should I place it? (right before and after which line?)

Comment: Actually, try leaving the code where it was and changing $post->ID to $wp_query->post->ID since you're outside the loop.

Comment: @aendrew it worked, thanks for helping me today! so what happened when I changed $post->post->ID for $wp_query->post->ID?

Comment: No problem, glad to help! $post is the post variable that WP uses inside of a loop; $wp_query accesses the post query directly. $post->ID is the interior scope of $wp_query->post->ID -- notice the similarity? Regardless, I'm not entirely sure why $post->ID didn't work if you were on a specific page, though I'm guessing it has something to do with all the custom queries you build earlier on in the file.